# Android Locationprovider takes too long to become temporarily unavailable

Tags: android, location

According to this article (**UPD:** link removed as it leads to some crap now), setting the *minTime* when requesting location updates will cause the provider to set itself to TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE for *minTime* milliseconds in order to conserve battery power. During this period of inactivity, the GPS provider will turn itself off and the GPS icon will disappear.

In my code, I set the minTime to about 30 seconds, but the provider only becomes TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE once every five minutes. When it does, it only stays TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE for ten seconds at most before turning itself back on. I know this because the GPS icon disappears for only ten seconds before reappearing again.

I understand that the *minTime* setting is only a rough guideline for the Android location provider...but I'm pretty sure that five minutes is entirely different from 30 seconds. Does anyone know what is going on here? How does *minTime* and requestLocationUpdates actually work?

LocationManager Setup:

> ```
> locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
> locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,30000L, 0, locListener);
> ```

locListener:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    //Keep track of best location
    //Having a location > no location
    if (bestLocation == null)
        bestLocation = loc;
    //More accuracy > Less accuracy
    else if (loc.getAccuracy() <= bestLocation.getAccuracy())
        bestLocation = loc;

    Log.d(TAG, "Location Updated";
}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    Log.d(TAG, "New status: " + status);
    if (status== LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE)
        //Do stuff since the provider is temporarily off
}
```

Debug output on a real Android device (HTC Incredible 2.2):

```
Location Updated
Location Updated
New status: 2
Location Updated
Location Updated
Location Updated
New status: 2
... (five minutes later)
New status: 1
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the minDistance param? On the other hand, minTime should be considered _before_ minDistance. So it probably is not that.. -.-

Answer (score 0):

From the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

"Background services should be careful about setting a sufficiently high minTime so that the device doesn't consume too much power by keeping the GPS or wireless radios on all the time. In particular, **values under 60000ms are not recommended.**" (emphasis is mine)

"This field is only used as a **hint** to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value." (emphasis is mine).

If you need to know the location immediately, use [`getLastKnownLocation(String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)