# Android LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am trying to find out more information about LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE location status on Android.

I have a program that has to periodically poll device's GPS location.  I use requestLocationUpdates() and addGpsStatusListener() methods in the LocationManager class to register my listener.

Most of the time it works just fine.  However, occasionally a device would get into a mode where onStatusChanged() method would be called with status argument set to LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE and my program would not receive updates anymore.

Do you know what would cause the GPS device to become "Temporary Unavailable"?  I've been searching the internet but could not find anything useful.

Thanks.

Comment: possible repeat of thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213815/android-locationprovider-takes-too-long-to-become-temporarily-unavailable

Comment: Thanks that thread was very helpful.